# How to identify a bottleneck on a spark application(pyspark)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm having a slow performance in my pyspark application.
I have a function that involves 5 dataframes and theres joins and agregations inside.
When I call this function only once, it runs successfully.
But when I call it more than once, inside the process(only changing a parameter, but the data volume is the same) it does not terminate.
It stops in some part that I'm not able to identify.
My question is: How to debug my spark application to identify this bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

I generally test and troubleshoot my spark applications using the below steps

1. **master=local**

   Execute application/pipeline using `master=local` with small datasets. 
   Using this option i can run Spark application using my favorite IDE in local 
   desktop and can use debug option also.

```
   spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").config("master", "local").getOrCreate()
```

2. **--deploy-mode client**

   Once the issues are resolved and is working locally, package and deploy application to edgenode and execute in `client` mode with small datasets.  We can see any error messages/stacktraces etc in console, if any.
3. **--deploy-mode cluster**

   Now execute in `cluster` mode, with large/actual datasets and update settings for spark performance like no of executors, executor memory etc.